# Запятая после союза «и» или перед ним?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, и

Дано предложение с такой вот структурой.
*Он говорил, что...* (тут длинная часть с оборотами), *но он также говорил(,) и(,) что...*

Какая из этих двух запятых нужна? Союз **и** присоединяется ко второму **что** (согласно справочнику Розенталя) или тут другое правило?

Comment: Можно такое предложение придумать: ‟Он говорил, что очень устал пребывать в этом городе, но он также говорил, что там много хорошего”. Это ‟и” перед ‟что” здесь просто никак нельзя вставить. Я сомневаюсь, что такое предложение вообще возможно.

Comment: @Jim Korbett, зачем же вы удалили свой ответ? Я думала над ним) Смотрите, а если так: "Он говорил это (много слов), но он так же говорил и вот это (много слов)". Ведь такая структура существует? Но вы считаете, что в сочетании с союзом "что" она невозможна? Если что я абсолютно без претензий, я пытаюсь разобраться. Добавлю ещё, что это разговорная речь. Допустимо ли в таком случае?

Comment: Я ответил на вопрос, который неправильно воспринял. Я воспринял вопрос, как если бы союз ‟и” соединял два придаточных. Я не уверен, что вообще существуют предложения, где перед изъяснительным стоит ‟и” и при этом нет второго однородного изъяснительного с ‟и”, как предложения вроде: ‟Он сказал и что ему подарить, и как это достать. Скорее всего, такие предложения вообще никогда никем не произносились в истории.

Comment: Jim Korbett, правильно ли я понимаю, что на ваш взгляд "и" тут не может соединять два "что": Он говорил, что это и что вот это. Или тот ваш ответ, получается, об этом и был? А когда добавляется повтор "он также говорил" во вторую половину, то всё ломается?

Comment: Нет, такое предложение возможно: ‟Он говорил, что устал и что его утомили именно они”. Опять же, проблема в одиночном ‟и” перед изъяснительным придаточным: я сомневаюсь, что такие предложения вообще существуют. Если это какая-то сумбурно-разговорная речь, то тут вообще нельзя определить, какие знаки следует ставить, так как для расстановки запятых необходимо знать, что человек хочет выразить, какие функции выполняют те или иные союзы и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: ***Он говорил, что ... (тут длинная часть с оборотами), но он также говорил и что...***

1. Запятая перед союзом И не ставится согласно правилу Розенталя

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137

Пункт 4. Между главной и следующей за ней придаточной частью сложноподчиненного предложения запятая не ставится:
2) если перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом стоит сочинительный союз и, ни … ни, или, либо и т. п. (обычно повторяющийся): Учтите и что он сказал, и как он это сказал; Я знаю **и как** это делается; Мальчика прощали **и когда** он никого не слушался.

2. Для постановки второй запятой (перед ЧТО) также нет оснований. Общая структура предложения выглядит так: Он говорил, что(...), но он также говорил и (что...).

Противительный сочинительный союз НО связывает два сложноподчиненных предложения, но перед вторым СПП стоит присоединительный союз И. Здесь нет общей главной части, каждое придаточное относится к своему главному предложению.